# How to redesign Swing,AWT based app for Android using View, LayoutManager

Tags: java, android, swing, view

I have a protootype of an app written using Java Swing, AWT classes to do routine stuff such as allowing entry into a JTexfield along with JButton(s) to allow selection from one of several values, and then to append selected button value into the JTexfield (so as to construct a mathematical equation). As a newbie to Android, I am  struggling to map the resources in Java Swing to Android equivalents. I want to use it's xml based capability to define the UI where possible and programatically to control behaviour. Lokking for any advice on how to translate between these 2 frameworks.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.text.JTextComponent;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class MathYr1GUI extends JFrame
{
    private static final String TITLE="Number Bonds to 10 ";
    private static final int WIDTH=450;
    private static final int HEIGHT=600;

    private Container content;
    private JLabel result;
    private JButton[] cells;
    private JButton exitButton;
    private JButton initButton;
    private JButton enterButton;
    private CellButtonHandler[] cellHandlers;
    private ExitButtonHandler exitHandler;
    private InitButtonHandler initHandler;
    private EnterButtonHandler enterHandler;

    private boolean noughts;
    private boolean gameOver;

    private JTextField answer;
    private double testnumber;
    private double twenty=20;
    public double ten=10;

    public MathYr1GUI()
    {
        //Necessary initialization code
        setTitle(TITLE);
        setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        //Get content pane
        content=getContentPane();
        content.setBackground(Color.blue.darker());

        answer = new JTextField(10);



        //Set layout
        content.setLayout(new GridLayout(4,3));

        //Create cells and handlers
        cells=new JButton[9];
        cellHandlers=new CellButtonHandler[9];
        for(int i=0; i<9; i++)
        {
            char ch=(char)('0'+i+1);
            cells[i]=new JButton(""+ch);
            cellHandlers[i]=new CellButtonHandler();
            cells[i].addActionListener(cellHandlers[i]);
        }

        //Create init and exit buttons and handlers
        enterButton = new JButton("Submit");
        enterHandler = new EnterButtonHandler();
        enterButton.addActionListener(enterHandler);

        exitButton=new JButton("EXIT");
        exitHandler=new ExitButtonHandler();
        exitButton.addActionListener(exitHandler);
        initButton=new JButton("CLEAR");
        initHandler=new InitButtonHandler();
        initButton.addActionListener(initHandler);


        //Create result label
        result=new JLabel("Noughts", SwingConstants.CENTER);
        result.setForeground(Color.white);

        //Add elements to the grid content pane
        for(int i=0; i<9; i++)
        {
            content.add(cells[i]);
        }
        content.add(initButton);
        content.add(result);
        content.add(exitButton);
        content.add(answer, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        content.add(enterButton);
        //Initialize
        init();
    }

    public void init()
    {
        //Initialize booleans
        noughts=true;
        gameOver=false;

        //Initialize text in buttons
        for(int i=0; i<9; i++)
        {
            char ch=(char)('0'+i+1);
            cells[i].setText(""+ch);
        }

        //Initialize result label
        result.setText("Noughts");

        setVisible(true);
        answer.setText("0");
    }



    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        //Create TicTacToe object
        MathYr1GUI gui=new MathYr1GUI();

    }

    private class CellButtonHandler implements ActionListener
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            //If game over, ignore
            if(gameOver)
            {
                return;
            }

            //Get button pressed
            JButton pressed=(JButton)(e.getSource());

            //Get text of button
            String text=pressed.getText();

            //If noughts or crosses, ignore
            if(text.equals("O") || text.equals("X"))
            {
                return;
            }

            //Add nought or cross
            if (testnumber + Double.parseDouble(text) ==ten)
            {
                //End of game
                gameOver=true;
                result.setText("WELL DONE!");

                //Display winner message
            }
            else
            {
                result.setText("OOPS! TRY AGAIN");

            }

        }
    }

    private class EnterButtonHandler implements ActionListener
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            testnumber = Double.parseDouble(answer.getText());
            result.setText( (answer.getText().trim() + " + __ = 20").toString() ) ;

        }

    }

    private class ExitButtonHandler implements ActionListener
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }


    private class InitButtonHandler implements ActionListener
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            init();
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: As you have already figured out the Swing framework and Android UI framework are two different frameworks, and I don't believe you will find anything that will automate the conversion for you. Instead I would urge you to take a look at the documentation at Android.com, e.g. the "Building a Simple User Interface" which introduces some of the concepts: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/building-ui.html and the "Input Controls" sub-pages which describes how to use the basic widgets: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls.html

Comment: Thanks, those links look like ideal for the type of applications I want to start with on Android.